# Reading a tab delimited file but whenever any unformatted line arrive it should ignore those line and keep prosessing from next line

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

1) I have a text file below like this.

> ```
> Sanjay    sn.mehta@gmail.com  123
> Ajay  ap123@yahoo.com 456
> Vijay vijymalya@gmail.com 789
> Sujay spnakum@tahoo.com   141
> Jay   jaybhalara@yahoo.com    275
> Dhananjay dh@gmail.com    786
> ```

2) My Code below is perfect for reading this text file and inserting data into database.
Here's my Code. I'm using **C#**

```
//Reading all lines of Text file
string[] alllines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\test1.txt");
for (int i = 1; i < alllines.Length; i++)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =      @"DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated   Security=True;User Instance=True";
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
//each word in line will be store in array when tab dilimiter arrive
string[] items = alllines[i].Split(new char[] { '\t','\n' }).ToArray<string>();
string Name = items[0].ToString();
string Email = items[1].ToString();
string Pwd = items[2].ToString();
//insert each word into database
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employees values('" + Name + "','" + Email +"','" + Pwd + "')";
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 conn.Dispose();
 Label1.Visible = true;
 Label1.Text = "Data Successfully Inserted into Database.";
 }
```

3)But My code is not able to read a text file when file is like...

> ```
> Sanjay    sn.mehta@gmail.com  123
> Ajay  ap123@yahoo.com 456
> Vijay vijymalya@gmail.com 789
> ------------------------------------------
> Sujay spnakum@tahoo.com   141
> Jay   jaybhalara@yahoo.com    275
> Dhananjay dh@gmail.com    786
> ```

4)What i want is only that whenever that kind of unformatted line arrive it should ignore it and process next line. OR Whenever delimiter arrive it start processing

5)You can use StreamReader and can read file line by line.

Comment: 1. Pull your db connection out of your for loop. 2. Use a foreach for your loop. 3. If your string doesnt split into 3 parts, throw it out.

Comment: 4. You should never concatenate strings to insert your sql variables.  Use parameters instead.

Comment: I know that if my string doesn't split into 3 part than i've to throw it out but don't knowing logic please can you explain sir...I'm new to this language...

Answer (score 0):

The `if(items.Length != 3)` will tell you if the split happened properly.

Some of the changes I made are:

1. used a using statement for the sql connection
2. used var to instantiate a variable
3. Added the if statement to test for a valid split
4. used a foreach loop instead of a for loop for easier readability
5. moved the status outside the loop so that it would only show at the end.
6. Used ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader.  The statement doesnt return anything, so a reader is not needed.

Here's the code.

```
//Reading all lines of Text file
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\test1.txt");
var connectionString = @"DataSource=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Database.mdf;Integrated   Security=True;User Instance=True";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    foreach (var line in allLines)
    {
        var items = line.Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }).ToArray();
        if (items.Length != 3)
            continue;
        var Name = items[0].ToString();
        var Email = items[1].ToString();
        var Pwd = items[2].ToString();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employees values('" + Name + "','" + Email + "','" + Pwd + "')";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    Label1.Visible = true;
    Label1.Text = "Data Successfully Inserted into Database.";
}
```

Also, [Using parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your sql is much more secure.  As this is written, you are vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

EDIT:

To use a streamreader it would look like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        //contents of foreach loop go here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir It shows me error that "Keyword not supported:'datasource'.

Comment: @Chiraag, that would be your connection string.  Oh, I believe its supposed to be `Data Source` not `DataSource`.  If so, your original post has it wrong.

Comment: And sir what if i have to use stram reader for reading a file...then what would be the logic?? Is there any way to read this file by stream reader and line by line?

Comment: @Chiraag, check my latest edit.  dont forget to upvote and mark as answer!  Good luck!

Comment: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.IO.StreamReader' because 'System.IO.StreamReader' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @Chiraag Sorry if I wasnt clear.  The while statement does what your foreach does, so the foreach is removed.  You should be able to replace the foreach with the using / while statement completely.